# Apex REST request requires attributes field

Tags: apex, apexrest

I just spun up a new production org and I am getting the following error when trying to send a POST request to my REST endpoint.

`Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must have an attributes field before any other fields.`

POST Request

```
{
   "account": {
      "name": "test"
   }
}
```

Apex Class

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/leadImport')
global without sharing class LeadImportRequestHandler {

    global class ResponseMessage {
        public Boolean isSuccess;
        public String message;
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static ResponseMessage doPost() {
        ResponseMessage response = new ResponseMessage();
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse restRes = new RestResponse();
        Account account = new Account();

        try {            
            String body = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
            account = (Account)JSON.deserialize(body, sObject.class);
            req = RestContext.request;
            restRes = RestContext.response;
            insert account;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            restRes.statusCode = 400;
            response.isSuccess = false;
            response.message = e.getMessage();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

The class throws the error on the following line of code
`account = (Account)JSON.deserialize(body, sObject.class);`

I know sending the below request solves the issue but for other Salesforce orgs I have worked on I simply sent the first request and it worked fine. The difference between the new org is the apex class is not associated with a Sites page where classes on the previous orgs are. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Working Request

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "type": "Account"
    },
    "name": "test"
}
```

Comment: try to change sObject.class to account.class

Comment: off topic, but why don't you just do  `restRes.statusCode = response.getStatusCode();`

Comment: @EricSSH the getStatusCode() method is an HttpResponse class method. So this wouldn't work in this situation since I am using my own wrapper class, ResponseMessage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [`JSON` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm):

```
Object deserialize(String jsonString, System.Type apexType)
```

Deserializes the specified JSON string into an Apex object of the specified type.

You can use sObject with attributes, or specify exact class type:

```
string body = '{"account":{"name":"test"}}';
Account acc = (Account)JSON.deserialize(body, Account.class);
system.debug(acc);

USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|Account:{Name=test}
```

Comment: How would one deserialize this in JS instead of Apex code? I'm using JSForce and running into this same error, but I don't have access to the `Account.class` object